# Using 'Used to' correctly

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence

> I used to be wandering at 7 a.m

Correct?

Or should i just say

> I used to wander at 7 a.m

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context and intended meaning.

> My friend called at 7 AM.  I used to be wandering at 7 a.m., but
>   lately I've been staying in.

Comment: So "used to + be + verb ing" is acceptable? I used to be wandering while looking for chicks at/around 7 a.m.